# Determine number of row in matrix with duplicate rows

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I return the number (place) of the row in a given matrix?
At first I thought I could do it with board.index(row), but in this case:

```
board = [[1,1,1,1],
         [2,2,2,2],
         [3,3,3,3],
         [1,1,1,1]]
for row in board:
    print board.index(row)
```

it returns 0 1 2 0, because the first and the last row are alike.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try:**

```
board = [[1,1,1,1],
         [2,2,2,2],
         [3,3,3,3],
         [1,1,1,1]]

for i, row in enumerate(board):
    print board.index(row, i)
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
2
3
```

**Explanation:**

```
index(value, [start, [stop]])
```

In my code, I'm using **enumerate** to simulate the current index of each board in the loop. Then, I'm asking **`index`** method to search for certain **value** but starting from its **index** (the one that enumerate provides me).

Answer (score 0):

```
board = [[1,1,1,1],
         [2,2,2,2],
         [3,3,3,3],
         [1,1,1,1]]
count = 1
for row in board:
    print count
    print board.index(row)
    count = count + 1
```